# Select row with smallest number on multiple groups of same ids

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following table as an output from a sql statement

```
user | product | price 
          …
123  | 12     | 451.29
373  | 12     | 637.28
623  | 12     | 650.84
672  | 16     | 356.87
123  | 16     | 263.90
          …
```

Now I want to get only the row with the smallest price for each product_id

THE SQL is fairly easy

```
SELECT user, product, price
        FROM t
        WHERE product IN (
            SELECT product_id
            FROM p
            WHERE typ LIKE 'producttyp1'
        )
)
```

but adding MIN(price) does not work how it usually do. I think its because there are several groups of the same product_ids in the same table. Is there an easy to use solution or do I have to rewrite the whole query?

Edit: when I delete user from the query I can get the product and the smallest price:

```
12 | 451.29
16 | 263.90
```

But now I would have to join the user, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: . . Your query really has nothing to do with getting the smallest price.  I'm wondering what you are thinking (`price` isn't even mentions in the query).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by price asc) as seqnum
      from p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: does this solution mean that I just take the first row from each group? which has the smallest price after ordering it

Comment: @Tim4497 . . . You explained that quite well.